# How to access custom properties for the Image Gallery web part?

Tags: web-part, spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework

I'm attempting to create a sharepoint page programatically by adding an image gallery web part.  How do I access the properties of that web part?  I don't see the documentation anywhere for Image Gallery like I do for the Image web part.  [Custom Properties for Image Web Part](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Image-Web-Part-5427941B-10BC-4E5F-8C3F-68637608034D#bm4)

Comment: Are you trying to add the webpart to a classic webpart page, or a modern page?

Comment: I am adding it to a modern page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you go to the hosted workbench (_layouts/15/workbench.aspx) and configure the canvas how you want, select the "Web Part Data" button on the top left.  That will pop up a window with the serialization format for both modern and classic.  The value in the "Modern Pages" tab is the value that should be stored in the canvas field.